# IClaimsTransformation not firing for GraphQL with Authentication.JwtBearer v6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

## Update

The following log message is probably the root cause

```
    System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.InternalValidators.ValidateLifetimeAndIssuerAfterSignatureNotValidatedJwt(Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken, System.Nullable`1<System.DateTime>, System.Nullable`1<System.DateTime>, System.String, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters, System.Text.StringBuilder)'.\n  
    at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)\n   
    at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)\n   
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()",
```

## Original post

We have a project in which we use an `IClaimsTransformation` implementation to modify the roles in the JWT. This worked fine for both traditional HTTP endpoint and the GraphQL endpoint of our service with the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer v5.0.12` package.

When we update this package to version `6.0.0` it stops working for the GraphQL endpoint.
Is this because of a known change (which i cannot find anything about) in the package or is this a bug? If this is as intended how do we get it working again?

List of all packages:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Conventions.NodaTime" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Relay" Version="0.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Authorization.AspNetCore" Version="5.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Transports.AspNetCore" Version="5.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Transports.AspNetCore.SystemTextJson" Version="5.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Ui.Altair" Version="5.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="4.1.0" />
```

ConfigureServices

```
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddGraphQL(
                    (options, provider) =>
                    {
                        var logger = provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Startup>>();
                        options.UnhandledExceptionDelegate = ctx =>
                        {
                            logger.LogError(ctx.OriginalException, "Unhandled exception in graphQL");

                            // CloudPrint specific exception unlikely to leak sensitive information in its message
                            if (ctx.OriginalException.GetType().FullName!.StartsWith("CloudPrint."))
                                ctx.ErrorMessage = ctx.OriginalException.Message;

                            var requestId = GetRequestId(ctx);
                            if (requestId != null)
                                ctx.Exception.Data["RequestId"] = requestId;
                        };
                    })
                // Adds all graph types in the current assembly with a singleton lifetime.
                .AddGraphTypes()
                .AddDataLoader()
                .AddSystemTextJson()
                .AddGraphQLAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("create", p => p.RequireRole("create"));
                    // other policies removed to reduce size of post
                });
            services.AddTransient<IValidationRule, AuthorizationValidationRule>();
            services.AddTransient(typeof(ConnectionType<>))
                .AddTransient(typeof(EdgeType<>))
                .AddTransient<NodeInterface>()
                .AddTransient<PageInfoType>();

            services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>(); // <------ Our transformation implementation
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", options => { })
            .AddJwtBearer(config =>
            {
                config.Authority = Configuration["Jwt:Authority"];
                config.Audience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
                config.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateAudience = true
                };
            }); 

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("BasicAuthentication", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("BasicAuthentication").RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
            });
```

Note I have not included the code of `ClaimsTransformer` because I already have observed with the debugger that the `TransformAsync` method is never called so its implementation is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `InternalValidators.ValidateLifetimeAndIssuerAfterSignatureNotValidatedJwt` really seems to be missing from `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens 6.15.0` downgrading this package to 6.14.1 solved the issue.

Digged a bit deeper looks like it is [this issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1792)